# Who pays for the damages in this Asiana-Aeroflot collision?

Tags: safety, incidents, liability

I just came across this article where an an Asiana 747 'collided' with an Aeroflot IL62 at the adjacent gate. As per the reports, IL62 had to be scrapped. From, what I read, it was like the Asiana pilot had a brain freeze.

I was wondering, in this case who payed for the damages and what happened to the pilots?

Here is the [accident description from aviation-safety.net](http://aviation-safety.net/database/record.php?id=19981111-1) and here's a photo of the 747's wingtip embedded in the vertical stabilizer of the IL-62:

[image]

Comment: mind the main reason the Il-62M would be scrapped is likely that the aircraft was already old and scheduled to be taken out of service, they just did that early rather than repairing it for a few months.

Comment: [Probable cause](http://www.ntsb.gov/investigations/_layouts/ntsb.aviation/brief.aspx?ev_id=20001211X11355&key=1): excessive speed, according to NTSB.

Comment: The airline's insurance will have picked this up. Who else?

Comment: @SentryRaven I was wondering, which airlines insurance... because it was the fault of Asiana pilot.

Comment: Same as with cars: the offending party's insurance. So the Asiana insurance should pay.

Comment: Reading the ASN article and looking at the pictures, it says something quite positive about the strength of the 747's wingtips! Not pictured and barely mentioned was that the #1 engine of the 747 hit the wing of the IL62 prior to the wing-tail interaction. You can see the wing tip of the IL62 looking pretty ragged in the posted image, if you start looking closely.

Answer (score 7):

**Short answer:**
Someone's insurance company is writing a check.

**Longer answer:**
What usually happens in the insurance world is ***both insurance companies write checks*** to repair their respective clients' aircraft.  The insurance companies may then fight it out between themselves to determine who is responsible for what, *if it makes financial sense to do so*.

In cases where injuries or deaths result from an incident it almost always makes sense for the insurance companies to fight it out(those payouts can run in the millions of dollars).

In cases like this where there's only equipment damage the cost of the repair will determine how aggressively Aeroflot's insurance carrier pursues getting their money back from Asiana's carrier.  If we're talking about extensive and expensive structural repairs into the millions of dollars Aeroflot's insurance carrier will be motivated to get someone else to pay the bill. Conversely if the insurance company can make their money back through Aeroflot's premiums and pursuing Asiana for negligence or something along those lines to try to get them to pay for the repair would ultimately cost more (money and time pursuing the case) than just absorbing the loss the insurance carrier will just absorb the loss.